# SQL, Struggling to believe HAVING can be more efficient than a join

Tags: sql, oracle, database, database-performance, query-performance

I Am trying to find Players that have played in more than one game for a team in the following tables (** denotes private key), and find it hard to believe the best query I can come up with (below) is the most efficient. Ideas on how to improve it, and explanations as to why would be much appreciated (Trying to learn SQL)

```
Team (*tid*, name)
Game (*gid*, tid)
Player (*gid*, *name*)

SELECT Team_Name, Player_Name

  FROM (SELECT GID, TID FROM GAME) G
      ,(SELECT NAME AS Player_Name, GID FROM PLAYER) P
      ,(SELECT NAME AS Team_Name, TID FROM TEAM) T

  WHERE (     G.GID = P.GID
          AND Player_Name IN (SELECT P.NAME
                                FROM GAME G
                                    ,PLAYER P
                                WHERE G.GID = P.GID
                                GROUP BY P.NAME
                                HAVING COUNT(P.NAME) > 1)
          AND T.TID = G.TID
        )

  GROUP BY Team_Name, Player_Name
  HAVING COUNT(Player_Name) > 1
  ORDER BY Team_Name
```

Comment: Could you give us sample data and expected output to understand better? Also, I think the table design is a little wrong. `Player` just has `gid` and `name`. `gid` in `game` can have two teams. So `player.gid` will be constant while the team can be different in `game.tid`. More problems will come if the player name is the same.

Comment: Inside Player there is also a PID field, and there is a MEMBEROF Table. Since there were unnecessary for the query I left them out. The spec states that no two players will have the same name, I probably should have included that. Looking back i can see the potential for confusion!
The Idea is to list all players that have played in two games along with the team they played in (so this includes any transfers etc, they have to have played two games but not necessarily with the same team

Answer (score 2):

You're asking which players have played in more than a single game.

```
SELECT P.Player_Name
FROM Player P
GROUP BY P.Player_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT P.GID) > 1
```

That will return all players who have played in more than 1 game (GID).

If you'd like to also GROUP BY team, then do this:

```
SELECT P.Player_Name, T.Team_Name
FROM Player P
    JOIN Game G ON P.GID = G.GID
    JOIN Team T ON G.TID = T.TID
GROUP BY P.Player_Name, T.Team_Name
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT G.GID) > 1
```

It seems odd to have the GID in the Player table.  Perhaps having a PlayerGames table would make more sense that stored the PlayerId and GameId -- better for database normalization.  The Player table should only store a single record for each player.

Also, what is the real association between the player and the team.  In this scenario, you're saying a player has to play a game, and a game has to have a team (or should a game have 2 or more teams).  Let us know what you're going for, and we could help present your best option.

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, If you see my comment on the original post in response to Orangecrush I realise that I should have explained things a little better.
The GROUP BY Query does exactly what I am after (ie the same as mine) but unfortunately seems less efficient than the original query.
This is the real issue, I find it hard to believe the original is the most efficient yet cannot think of anything better!

Comment: Not sure I'm following you -- these queries are your most efficient... Your original query is a mess :)  You have multiple GROUP BYs, multiple table scans, etc... Might be best for you to build a SQL Fiddle with an example (sqlfiddle.com).  Worse case, use my first query (can't get any more efficient than it) and use PlayerId IN ().  Good luck.

Comment: I am running the queries on an Oracle Database via aqua data studio.
The execution plans suggest a node cost of 10 for the Query I had posted, as opposed to 11 for yours. The Original also used considerably less memory.
This is the reason I posted in the first place, I agree to the best of my knowledge the join method you used (and i had priorly tried) should be more efficient, yet it appears the way the DBMS handles it, its not!